# Mongo update on all documents slow

Tags: mongodb, performance

I have a simple query that I want to run on two different collections (each collection has around 50K records) :

```
db.collectionA.updateMany({}, { $mul: { score: 0.3 } });
db.collectionB.updateMany({}, { $mul: { score: 0.8 } });
```

So basically I want to multiply the field `score` by a certain amount. On collectionA it takes 2-3s and on collectionB it takes ~50s. I noticed that I don't have any index on the field `score` on collection A (which is a dynamic field, updated very often) and for some reason I have a composed index with this field on collectionB.

My question is simple, why does it take so much time for mongo to execute this query and what can I do to make it faster ?

Thanks

Comment: There could be several reasons for a slow query !! Why don't you read this :: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html & then come to a conclusion on your own with what's happening in your DB, then you can raise a new question with a exact issue, Once you get to know about the content in that page (MongoDB Documentation) I believe you would've  better knowledge on how to deal with this issue :-)

Comment: I know about the explain() method but it doesn't give me much information there

Comment: If you already know about explain, can you share it’s output for both cases?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have answered the question yourself: there is an index on that field in the second collection, and on changing the value in a document, that index needs recalculation. You could try to drop that index and re-create it after the update has finished

Comment: So after each individual updates done by the updateMany, mongo will recalculate the index? I thought it might just do it once at the end. I'll try the drop and recreate and let you know. Would there be a way to go down that 2-3s (on collectionA), since to me 3s for 50k records seems still kinda slow. Thanks